# Selenium script timing out after 2000 pages, what should i do with this?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

This is not going past 2000 clicks it gives me timed out error

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/akshatagarwal/Desktop/chromedriver')
driver.get(uri)
clicks = 0
for i in range(6600):
    text = driver.page_source
    file = open('src.txt', 'a')
    file.writelines(text)
    file.close()
    plus = driver.find_element_by_id("next")
    plus.click()
```

Comment: Try using recursion to start the script  from where you left - when the timeout occurred.

Comment: The problem is I will have to start from the beginning because the webpage i am trying to get to have a javascript script that results the list on the same page without changing the url.

Comment: usually JavaScript uses some url to get data and usually you can find this url in DevTools (tab: Network) and use this url to get data without using `Selenium` - and then you may no need to start from beginning but you may have to use only correct parameters in url.